# Prevent Android Studio/Intellij Idea from building project on startup

Tags: android, build, intellij-idea, project, android-studio

When I open Android Studio, it loads the last project, and runs build. I really don't need it to do this. If I save a project with errors in it, because I haven't got time to fix them, but plan on doing it later, I don't really want the compiler to try to compile it next time I open the project, because it's just going to fail.

Also it's pointless building the project on startup even if it doesn't have errors, because if the project doesn't have errors, I always build it to test it before I stop working on it, so the new build will be completely redundant. Thanks if anyone knows of a way to disable this. I've tried Googling and searching the settings but can't find anything.

Edit: this has become even more annoying since I moved to a slower computer for development. It already takes long enough for Android Studio to start up, having the program build just slows the startup even more.

Comment: IntelliJ by default doesn't build your project on start up, even when your project contains error. Android Studio probably does something different.

Comment: Good news: This has been added as a feature for 0.2.2. They've been doing weekly updates, so hopefully this will be available by Friday. (https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/62462/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've confirmed with a Google software engineer that this is currently not an option as of Android Studio 0.2.1. ( See 5th comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+XavierDucrohet/posts/1R2iPQzo4Zh )

I've also opened the following ticket as the engineer suggested:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57831&thanks=57831&ts=1374268538

Hopefully this will be resolved in the near future! Until then, I guess we'll have to open Android Studio and grab a cup of coffee while the build completes.

Comment: No problem! I have a big project, and it takes forever to open when the pointless auto build kicks off.

Comment: This has now reverted to the old behaviour of fully building the project when reopening it. Do you have any information on whether this will stay like this, or if a preference has been added to disable it? Thanks.

Comment: I think it somehow got pared down to a subset of the build process upon loading Android Studio, and honestly I never noticed anything ever being noticeably better. :( My guess is that somebody at Google really wanted to keep it there.

Comment: I did notice an improvement, it stopped running a full compile on startup, but now, since 0.2.8 or thereabouts, it started again. I've put a comment on the ticket you opened. I do think the engineer at Google who argued against having this as an option was misguided. Intellij Idea/Android Studio already has thousands of confusing options, one more isn't going to make a difference, especially not to programmers. Though if this is the default behaviour with Idea I guess it's not really Google's fault.

Comment: I wish I can code Android in Visual Studio... I want to go back to the darkside.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm in latest version `0.8.x` this functionality can be prevented by unchecking the `Reopen last project on startup` box in `File -> Settings -> General`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have `Make project automatically` enabled.

This setting can be found in `Settings -> Project Settings -> Compiler`, under the `Use external build` setting.

You can also try disabling the `Rebuild module on dependency change` setting (it is in the same place).

Comment: Thanks, but even with both of these unchecked, it still builds automatically at startup (or when you open a project).

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version (0.2.6) the switch is in

File/Settings - General under tick box 'Reopen last project on startup'

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Studio(v135.1740770) in Mac Pro, open below file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/options/ide.general.xml
```

you will see option for autoSyncFiles, just change its value to false.

```
<option name="autoSyncFiles" value="false" />
```

Hope this helps.